# Add empty cells in table in Latex

Tags: tables, threeparttable

I want to put some empty cells in Table so my table has the first row with numbers and the next the first cell only empty.

I also used note under the table but there is error that I couldn't resolve.

```
\begin{table}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample of table}
     \begin{tabular}{c | c | c |  c}
        \toprule
         \textbf{$Set$}  & \textbf{$d_t$} 
      &\textbf{$d_{mt}$}  & \textbf{$d_{ms}$} 
        \midrule

         A    & 122    &30    & 6.0003\\
              &(3)     &(27)  &(5)\\
         B    & 150    &26    &4  \\
              &(4)     &(2)   &(3)\\
         C    & 5      & 1.5  & 1 \\
              &(4)     &(1)   &(2)\\

        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
   \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: It seems to me that your table already has some empty cells. Please explain more about what you are looking for.

Comment: please extent your code fragment to complete small document with your table. in preamble are information which might be source of your problems. in your table the first row is not terminated properly (missed are `\\`)

Comment: I don't see where is the problem. log file problem is \midrule misplace \noaligned

Comment: you are missing `\\ ` before the `\midrule`

Comment: unrelated but `\textbf{$d_{ms}$}` is the same as `$d_{ms}$` as math mode is unaffected by the text font outside the math. Perhaps you intended `\boldmath $d_{ms}$` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\tabhead}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\rothead}[1]{\rotatebox{45}{\tabhead{#1}}}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}
 \begin{center}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample of table}
     \begin{tabular}{c | c | c |  c}
        \toprule
         \textbf{$Set$}  & \textbf{$d_t$}  &\textbf{$d_{mt}$}  & \textbf{$d_{ms}$} \\ % you missed \\ 
        \midrule
         A    & 122    &30    & 6.0003\\
              &(3)     &(27)  &(5)\\
         B    & 150    &26    &4  \\
              &(4)     &(2)   &(3)\\
              &        &      & \\
              &        &      & \\
         C    & 5      & 1.5  & 1 \\
              &(4)     &(1)   &(2)\\
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
   \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding the missing `\\`  back in, which was, as also noted in the comments, the inital cause of the error message, I made some more adjustments to the table code. All changes are commented in the following MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage[hmargin=3cm]{geometry}   
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{threeparttable} Do not load packages more than once.


\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\centering  % Removed the center environment since it adds vertical white space. Instead you can use the \centering command
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample of table}
     \begin{tabular}{c  c  c   c} % horizontal lines from the booktabs package are intended to be used without vertical lines. I thus removed vertical lines.
        \toprule
         \textbf{Set}  & \boldmath $d_t$ 
      & \boldmath$d_{mt}$  & \boldmath $d_{ms}$ \\ % added missing \\ back in, Removed math mode from "set". Do not use math mode for text. Replaced \textbf around the other column headers with \boldmath
        \midrule

         A    & 122    &30    & 6.0003\\
              &(3)     &(27)  &(5)\\
         B    & 150    &26    &4  \\
              &(4)     &(2)   &(3)\\
         C    & 5      & 1.5  & 1 \\
              &(4)     &(1)   &(2)\\

        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\setlength\labelsep{0pt} % added to improve the alignment of the table notes.
      \small
      \item{} This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```